# What is known about the classification of ${\cal N}=4$ SCFTs with central charge 6?

Tags: resource-recommendations, conformal-field-theory, research-level, superconformality

I was talking about K3 surfaces with some physicists, and one of them told me that the ${\cal N}=4$ superconformal field theories with central charge 6 are expected to be relatively scarce.  In particular, one should expect a lot of a priori different theories (e.g., those coming from sigma models whose targets are different hyperkähler surfaces, or the Gepner model) to be isomorphic.  I have not found similar statements in the mathematical literature, but it sounds like a statement that, if suitably tweaked, could conceivably make sense to mathematicians.

**Question:** Where can I find such a claim (and perhaps additional justification)?

Also, I am curious to know if there are underlying physical principles behind such a claim, or if it was conjectured due to a scarcity of characters (i.e., the space of suitable modular/Jacobi forms is small), or perhaps some combination.

Answer (score 19):

For a survey on what was known in 1999 on the subject, there is the review [A Hiker's Guide to K3 - Aspects of N=(4,4) Superconformal Field Theory with central charge c=6](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9912067) by Werner Nahm and Katrin Wendland.  I have not been following this subject, so I am not sure whether the current picture is substantially different.

**Added**

Some of [the papers citing that review](http://arxiv.org/cits/hep-th/9912067) might also be relevant.

Comment: Thank you.  The Nahm-Wendland paper suggests that the moduli space of such theories is somewhat more subtle than I had been led to believe.